# Big O notation and Infinite series

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose I know $\displaystyle\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)=O(g(x))$. Can I deduce that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq x}f(n)=O(g(x))$?

I think it should be true, and if anything, it should be a weak bound.

Comment: I can think of Examples where it is true & Examples where it may not be true. It would be good to include some Example $f(n)$ & Example $g(x)$ in your Post , which will make the Query unambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Such a bound does not hold**. In fact, the tail of the (infinite) series can have a divergent sum.

Take $f(n) := n$. Hence,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^x f(n) = \frac{x(x+1)}{2} = O(g(x))
$$
where
$$
g(x) := x^2.
$$
But
$$
\sum_{n=x}^{+\infty} n = +\infty \neq O(g(x)).
$$

Comment: In my earlier Comment , I alluded to other Cases. [ Eg : $f(n)=0$ , $f(n)=1$ , $f(n)=n$ , $f(n)=n(-1)^n$ , $f(n)=2^{-n}$ , $f(n)=2^{+n}$ ] Various Cases arise , though OP Question is not focussed.